# Error while using bot.get_updates() for telegram bot in python

Tags: telegram-bot

I made a Telegram bot, and even after multiple tries, every time I try
`print(bot.get_updates())`, it returns me `[]`. I also ran a logging function, but it just says multiple instances are running, when I am running just one. What are the possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

> `print(bot.get_updates())`, it returns me `[]`

Then your didn't get any (new) updates yet.

> I also ran a logging function, but it just says multiple instances are running, when I am running just one. What are the possible reasons?

Only one process at a time may fetch updates from Telegram. Make sure that you have only one process running that fetches updates (either via `get_updates` or via a webhook)

Comment: I have been trying it out for like an hour now. It should have returned me at least a JSON format with chat id and everything. Is there any possible reason why am I not getting any then? @callmestag

Comment: `Is there any possible reason why am I not getting any then?` - There are a lot of possible reasons. To tell you more, you'd have to provide more info and probably a minimal code example.